# Утечка памяти в TObjectList

Tags: delphi

Не могу найти решение для устранении утечки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
type
  TMyObj = class
  Caption: string;
  Description: string;
  Params:string;
  ParamsLst: TStringList;

public
  constructor Create(const aPath: string; const aParams: TStrings); overload;
  destructor Destroy(); override;
end;

TDataList = class(TObjectList)
public
  constructor Create;
  // function LoadFromINI(IniFile: TMemIniFile): boolean;
  function Remove(Obj: TMyObj): Integer;
end;

var
  TObjData: TDataList;

implementation

constructor TMyObj.Create(const aPath: string; const aParams: TStrings);
begin
  Caption := aParams.Values['Caption'];
  Description := aParams.Values['Description'];
  Params := aParams.Values['Params'];
  if aParams.Values['Params'] <> '' then
  begin
    ParamsLst := TStringList.Create;
    try
      ExtractStrings([';', ','], [' '], PChar(Params), ParamsLst);
    except
      ParamsLst := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;

destructor TMyObj.Destroy;
begin
  ParamsLst.Free;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TDataList.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  OwnsObjects := True;
end;

function TDataList.Remove(Obj: TMyObj): Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited Remove(Obj);
end;

initialization
TObjData := TDataList.Create;

finalization
TObjData.Free;
```

заполнение TObjData, так

```
    TObjData.Add(TMyObj.Create(sVal, SecParams));
```

Comment: не вижу в Вашем коде типа `TTreeList`

Comment: исправлено TObjData

Comment: Зачем вам секции `initialozation & finalization`?  Почему не конструктор и деструктор?

Comment: @Victor если вы про классовые конструктор/деструктор, то очевидно, если объект не является синглтоном, то это не поможет. Если вы про обычные, то вообще не понятно при чем тут это.

Comment: для пустого списка без добавления элементов такая же ситуация?

Comment: А неубиваемый ParamsLst при исключении в ExtractStrings - это нормально?

Comment: В любом случае - штатный менеджер памяти не в состоянии показать, где конкретно возникла утечка. Для этого нужно подключить либо FastMM, либо MadExcept (последний - с включенной опцией отлова утечек). И вот когда у вас на руках благодаря этим инструментам будет полный stacktrace - тогда будет кристально ясно, где собака порылась.

Comment: @Victor, в данном случае вроде не существенно, но в целом, можно и изменить. Спасибо!

Comment: @teran, а вообщем, что все таки лучше использоват? Спасибо!

Comment: @Alekcvp, вполне возможно. Я проверю, спасибо!

Comment: У нас не форум, костыли вроде "РЕШЕНО!" бессмысленны. Если вопрос решён, ответьте использованный ответ галочкой (под стрелками голосования). Даже если этот ответ ваш собственный.

Comment: **Ещё раз: не добавляйте "Решено!" в заголовок вопроса, это не относится к вопросу вообще.** Решённость вопроса определяется наличием галочки у одного из его ответов. Если не можете поставить галочку сейчас сами (срок давности не позволяет), не нужно отмечать другими способами. Могут и другие ответы поступить.

Comment: И не убирайте из вопроса части вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код с учетом замечаний и предложений......

```
type
  TData = class
  private
    FCaption: string;
    FDescription: string;
    FParams: string;
    FParamsLst: TStringList;
    //....
  public
    constructor Create(const aPath: string; const aParams: TStrings);
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    property Caption: string read FCaption;
    property Description: string read FDescription;
    property Params: string read FParams;
    property ParamsLst: TStringList read FParamsLst;
    //...
  end;

  TDataList = class(TObjectList)
  private
   //...
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  property
    //...
  end;

var
  DataList: TDataList;

implementation

{ TData }
constructor TData.Create(const sPath: string; const sData: TStrings);
begin
  Caption := aParams.Values['..'];
  Description := aParams.Values['..'];
  Params := aParams.Values['..'];
  if aParams.Values['..'] <> '' then
  begin
    ParamsLst := TStringList.Create;
    try
      ExtractStrings([','], [' '], PChar(Params), ParamsLst);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

destructor TData.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end; { end TData }

{ DataList }
constructor TDataList.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  OwnsObjects := True;
end;

destructor TDataList.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end; { end DataList }
```

Решение, проблемы
    ......

```
procedure TMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Удаление списков в объекте
  for i := 0 to DataList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    with DataList.Items[i] do
    begin
      ParamsLst.Free;
    end;
  end;
// При удалении списка оставшиеся в нём объекты будут удалены.
  FreeAndNil(DataList);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Что касается исключения - точное место создания объекта, который не уничтожился  может показать FastMM или EurekaLog. Приведенный код рабочий и в большинстве случаев все правильно освобождается. (Нюансы описал ниже.) Скорее всего вы создается TreeList и его не уничтожаете (либо ждете что его уничтожит родительский объект, а он не назначен).

Остальные нюансы:

Может я что то упустил, но я не вижу откуда берутся данные для заполнения SecParams.

1. Если вы до момента добавления создали `SecParams` - его нужно уничтожить. Иначе будет утечка.

   ```
   TObjData.Add(TMyObj.Create(sVal, SecParams));
   ```
2. Второй участок `try..except`. При возникновении исключения - объект все же не уничтожится.

   ```
   ParamsLst := TStringList.Create;
   try
     ExtractStrings([';', ','], [' '], PChar(Params), ParamsLst);
   except
     ParamsLst := nil; // 
   end;
   ```

Хотя тоже не ясно, ну не обработались параметры, значит они в неправильном формате - объект создастся, но с пустым параметром ParamsLst. И если к нему обратится без проверки - будет `Access Violation`.

3. `TObjData` - есть общие правила когда с буквы T начинаются описания типов. F - для внутренних полей класса.

   ```
   var
     TObjData: TDataList;
   ```
4. Для полей класса `TMyObj` нужно явно указать идентификатор видимости (private, public), а еще лучше перенести их в секцию private и дать доступ к полям с помощью свойств. Например:

   ```
   type
     TMyObj = class
       FCaption: string;
     public
       ...
       property Caption: string read FCaption;
     end;
   ```
5. `TMyObj`  - название класса должно описывать объект. (Например: TPerson)

Comment: @androshuk, спасибо! Спасибо, за детальный и развернутый разбор моих "полетов", которые я обязательно учту.!

Comment: 1. SecParams уничтожается в блоке try finally

Comment: 2. **ParamsLst**, да меня уже, "ткнули", за этот код.

Comment: @Deda обращайтесь. Ждем результата. Что же вызвало утечку. Если какой то ответ правильный или натолкнул на мысль - отмечайте пожалуйста как ответ.

Comment: @androshuk, еще раз спасибо! Спасибо всем за предложения, все учел.
С учетом Ваших предложений (изменение стиля кода), проблему решил освобождением ParamsLst: TStringList до освобождения TDataList (присвоения по старому коду)
.....
property ParamsLst: TStringList read FParamsLst;
.....
 for i := 0 to TObjData.Count - 1 do
  begin
    with TObjData.Items[i] do
    begin
      TObjData.Items[i].ParamsLst.Free;
    end;
  end;

  // При удалении списка оставшиеся в нём объекты будут удалены.
  TObjData.Free;
......

Comment: Не понял, как отметить, как ответ!

Comment: @Deda  Немного не так сформулировал. Автор вопроса может пометить один из ответов «принятым». (Галочка в районе голосования).  [Подробности тут.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

1. В коде нет ни одного момента заполнения переменной со странным именем TObjData. Но могу предположить, что OwnsObjects не правильно срабатывает.
2. В финализации перед разрушением объекта TObjData лучше сделать цикл проверки вложенных в него объектов и выяснения по какой причине они не освобождаются до финализации.

Comment: с таким же успехом можно и брейкпоинт там поставить да посмотреть.

Comment: Всем, большое спасибо за выявленные недочеты и развернутые советы. Жаль, время не позволило давать оперативно ответы на заданные вопросы. Но, я обращу внимание на все рекомендации. Направление и методы поиска понятны, - по результатам изменений отпишусь.

Comment: @svd71, спасибо! Буду крутить.